# In IE8 new tabs are instantly closed

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

In IE8 whenever I try and open a new tab (either <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or the new tab button) the tab opens, then is closed straight away.
Any ideas how I can stop this happening?

(I can open new windows fine, but I much prefer tabs).

Comment: If this is recent and working before, check what you've changed on the IE setup, any new plugins?

Comment: ... or viruses?

Comment: No new plugins - only things likely to have changed are from windows updates.

No viruses I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved by uninstall IE8 and reinstall it.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. The following steps fixed it for me:

- go to Tools → Internet Options
- go to the Advanced tab
- click **Reset**
- after resetting to default settings, restart IE8
- after restarting IE click **Cancel** on the dialog box that comes up when IE8 is first used

I think some plugin that gets set by the dialog box is causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Probably addins or conflicting programs

Start it without extensions and see if it happens
**Run>iexplore -extoff**